# Is this sentence correct - "He broke into a chuckle as he heard it"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, phrase-choice

The person chuckles when he hears something - a joke or a funny anecdote.

Is the sentence in the question correct for such a setting or is there a better way to frame it? My main concern is the "broke into a chuckle" part. Is it okay to write it this way or is it odd?

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "broke into a chuckle" is perfectly valid, and not all that uncommon. Whether to use it is a matter of style, it gives a particular tone to the passage.

Answer (score 2):

Not odd at all! It's quite common. When you *break into something*, you *suddenly* start doing it. One can break into song (start singing), break into a run (start running).

A similar expression *burst into something* (whether into laughter, or into tears) has the same meaning and is equally commonly used.

Here is a list of the most popular things one can break into.

[image]

(Excluding the last two: breaking into pieces, and breaking [=getting] into a house)